# How can I parse the code that is conforming to a grammar expressed using ANTLR4 and then generate XML tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, antlr4, code-generation, grammar, xtext

I have specified a grammar using ANTLR4 using VScode and the extension by Mike Lischke. I am wondering if there is a way to parse the code of the program that is conforming to the grammar and generate eventually some XML tags.

Xtext provides this solution by generating a .xtend file that contains the famous doGenerate method, in which we access to objects and then generate a new code.

Comment: i guess the idea of a framework like Xtext or Langium is to take the burden from you to have to do this manually. is there a specific background about antlr4 or is it about having something running in vscode?

Comment: It is a ANTLR4 C++ grammar that exists already, and because adding new rules and the debugging task is much easier than when using xtext.
Our goal is to parse a code that is written in C++ and Gimple (multiple files) and generate some XML code that is compatible with a modelling tool called Capella in order to display the whole project using models in form of a functional architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s not a “write this parse tree out as XML” functionality built into ANTLR.

It would not be too hard to write a listener that produced XML while traversing the parse tree.  You’d have to make decisions about which property to include in you XML, as well as which to make attributes.

Probably, most people wanting to serialize to XML create an AST from the parse tree (parse trees can be rather verbose depending upon the grammar).  With an AST you could even annotate it, and use a library to serialize the AST as XML (using something like JaxB, for instance)

Comment: Thank you @mike-cargal, I am more comfortable with eclipse than with VSCode. This tutorial helped me a lot, [https://tutorial-academy.com/json-parser-antlr4-eclipse](https://tutorial-academy.com/json-parser-antlr4-eclipse/). I am using listeners in order to generate XML as you mentioned and follwing this [tutorial](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md).